# Why can say "diminishing weakened"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, expressions, meaning-in-context

The [resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIgGr.jpg) as:

> *However, the ability of the rainforest to pull in more carbon than it releases is diminishing weakened by changing weather patterns, deforeststation and increasing tree mortality, among other factors.*

---

Is the meaning of "diminishing" repeated with the one of "weakened"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the reasons for both "diminishing" and "weakened" seem fairly obvious despite the lack of a comma. This question might be better suited for ELL.

Comment: Read for comprehension as *the ability (of…diminishing)* is *weakened* by various factors.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a case of bad punctuation— that is all. The sentence reads fine, otherwise.

Consider this, for example:

> "However, the ability of the rainforest to pull in more carbon than it releases is **diminishing, weakened by** changing weather patterns, deforestation, and increasing tree mortality, among other factors."

Easy to make sense of, right?